# Streaming Android tablet display to notebook

Tags: android, python, perl, data-transfer, transmission

I'm recording (external and internal) sensor data on my Android tablet. Now I would like to stream these recorded sensor data over internet to my notebook / PC and display a graph of the data there. I have found this nice tutorial: http://simena86.github.io/blog/2013/04/30/logging-accelerometer-from-android-to-pc/

In this tutorial the data is streamed from Android over sockets to a python application which in turn uses a Perl script for plotting (I have never used perl before).

Now I would also like to stream the tablet display as well as the front cam recording (i.e. video data) from the tablet to the notebook / PC. Is there an easy way for doing this or can the above method be altered to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a VNC server on your tablet. There are several out there; I've used Alpha VNC. Then on the computer use a VNC viewer such as RealVNC to connect to it, and this will allow you to view the tablet screen on the PC.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds easy. And how can I view the front cam remotely?

Comment: @machinery open the camera app?

Comment: @simbabque But the user should not be disturbed, i.e. he should not notify it. I will conduct a study on the tablet and would like to observe the screen and front cam during the study.